# How to securely store pre-defined data in Android?

Tags: android, database, list, security, encryption

I am programming an app where I want to store a pre-defined encrypted list of strings. The idea is that the list contains a set of passwords that allow login to the app. I know how to let the user choose a password themself and save/encrypt them as sharedprefs so they cannot be extracted easily, however *I* want to define the passwords that allow login, so after installation the app needs to know whether the word is correct to let the user proceed.
The app does not and can not at any point connect to the internet so it has to work offline (= the list needs to be saved within the app somehow). It does not use Google/PlayStore.

I could do that in plain text like `String password = "word"`, but anyone looking at the code then knows the login. How could I save an encrypted list (or the like), that is being decrypted when the user wants to login?

Comment: while i'm no expert in this, i don't think there will ever be a completely safe way of doing this, it would be quite simple to brute force the app into trying all passwords till it eventually works using automation software

Comment: KeyStore probably helps you

Comment: In general, what you want is impractical. If your app can decrypt the data, so can the user. Specifically for passwords, though, you could have pre-computed hashes (e.g., bcrypt, scrypt) in the app. You would apply the one-way hash function to what the user enters and compare against your list of pre-computed hashes. This still could be brute-forced, depending on your password quality.

Comment: Yeah, what CommonsWare said - this is basically the same use case as allowing the user to set their own passwords, except you're the user and they come pre-stored. You still want to store them in the same way as a user password, in a way that can't (easily) be decrypted. If your app is able to decrypt that data, then anyone who finds that key can decrypt it - it's at risk! But if you're just storing hashes, then all you need to do is hash whatever the user enters, and check if it matches any of them

Comment: Thanks all for your responses - pre-computed hashes sounds like it might work. I am still completely lost how I'd do that. Do I generate a file that has the hashed passwords? How is it stored? How is it de-crypted? Is it simply two files that will be compared? I appreciate any pointers on how to programmatically do this. (Or other ways of doing this within an app that does not connect to the internet)